# Unable to Position Bottom Sheet Dialog at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, bottom-sheet

I have a Video Detail Fragment which I want to behave as a bottom sheet behaviour, but unfortunately, the dialog is getting displayed at the centre of the screen. I am unable to figure out the exact problem in the code. Below I am attaching the code and the layout file, in regard to the same.

**This is my Video Detail fragment:**

```
public class VideoDetailsFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AppCompatDialog dialog = new AppCompatDialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setTitle(titleId);
    return dialog;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_detail_fragment, container, false);
    Button cancelButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.track_selection_dialog_cancel_button);
    Button okButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.track_selection_dialog_ok_button);

    return dialogView;
}

public static final class TrackSelectionViewFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment
        implements TrackSelectionView.TrackSelectionListener {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exo_track_selection_dialog, container, /* attachToRoot= */ false);
        TrackSelectionView trackSelectionView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.exo_track_selection_view);
        trackSelectionView.setShowDisableOption(true);
        trackSelectionView.setAllowMultipleOverrides(allowMultipleOverrides);
        trackSelectionView.setAllowAdaptiveSelections(allowAdaptiveSelections);
        trackSelectionView.init(mappedTrackInfo, rendererIndex, isDisabled, overrides, /* listener= */ this);
        return rootView;
        }

    }

}
```

**The xml file for video_detail_fragment:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I went through many posts but almost all the posts were showing the solution as setting the app attribute `app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"`. But it's not working in my case. Kindly help me understand as to where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `270dp` as your root `LinearLayout` height? Shouldn't it be `wrap_content`? Or at least has a `android:gravity="bottom"`?

Comment: I tried using wrap content as well as gravity as bottom but it didn't yield me the desired output. So, just to be sure i used the fixed height.

Comment: Could you please add code for showing that bottom sheet dialog?